# Смена изображений на сайте из админ панели при помощи плагина

Tags: javascript, html, css, wordpress, изображения

Приветствую! Заменил названия изображений на сайте с русского на английский( латиницу) , когда открываешь сайт, и смотришь в панель администратора ( раздел сеть) то постоянно подгружаются те самые изображения что переименовывал с ошибкой 404 . В целом работа сайта не нарушена. Изображения отображаются но дополнительно грузиться старые названия с ошибкой от этого подозреваю грузиться сервер. Люди что делать то помогите!

Comment: как заменяли названия?

Comment: media rename плагином((

Comment: Поправка ошибка 403